# How do I choose to create a node based on whether it exists in the database in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I tried the following but it threw this error. I wish to only create a new person node if there isnt a person node in the existing database that has the exact same properties.

org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Invalid input 'R': expected

```
MERGE (n:Person{id: abc.id}) 
MERGE (m:Place{place:def.id}) 
MERGE (o:Thing{id:abcd.id})
WITH n,m,o
OPTIONAL MATCH (n) – [:present_at] -> x with n,m,o, collect (distinct x) as known_place
OPTIONAL MATCH (m) – [:is] -> y with n,m,o, collect (distinct y) as known_thing
FOREACH (a in ( CASE WHEN NOT m IN known_place THEN [1] ELSE [] END ) CREATE (n)-[:present_at] ->(m))
FOREACH (a in ( CASE WHEN NOT o IN known_thing THEN [1] ELSE [] END ) CREATE (m)-[:is] ->(o))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error was caused by a missing `|` in each of your [FOREACH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/foreach/) clauses. For example, this would fix that syntax error:

```
FOREACH (a in ( CASE WHEN NOT m IN known_place THEN [1] ELSE [] END ) | CREATE (n)-[:present_at] ->(m))
FOREACH (a in ( CASE WHEN NOT o IN known_thing THEN [1] ELSE [] END ) | CREATE (m)-[:is] ->(o))
```

However, your query would still have numerous other syntax errors.

In fact, the entire query could be refactored to be simpler and more efficient:

```
WITH {id: 123} AS abc, {id: 234} as def, {id: 345} AS abcd

MERGE (n:Person{id: abc.id}) 
MERGE (m:Place{place: def.id}) 
MERGE (o:Thing{id: abcd.id})
FOREACH (a in ( CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS((n)–[:present_at]->(m)) THEN [1] END ) | CREATE (n)-[:present_at]->(m))
FOREACH (a in ( CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS((m)–[:is]->(o)) THEN [1] END ) | CREATE (m)-[:is]->(o))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can I know what is id:123 referring to?

Comment: Im getting abc.id from another json file elsewhere.

Comment: The `WITH` clause is just adding some dummy data so that the rest of the query will actually be legal. You can ignore that clause.